# Automating number picker in android using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

How to automate number picker using espresso. I want to set specific time in the timePicker using espresso.

Comment: We need more details to help. Tell us what you've done so far, where you are getting stuck, and provide any relevant code.

Comment: @Maxwell I am using espresso and I want to select time from timepicker. I want to scroll through number picker to choose one number. I am able to click on number picker, and edit the text of selected number picker. Below is the code which I used: <onView(withText("12")).inRoot(isDialog()).perform(typeText(expectedMinute)); I want to actually scroll through number picker instead of directly setting the value by editing edit text widget. If that's not possible I want a way to identify number picker by class name, because it does not have any unique id or content description. Thanks for response

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To match a View by its class name you can simply use:

```
 onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(TimePicker.class.getName())));
```

Once you have the ViewInteraction object you can set a value on it defining and using a ViewAction as following:

```
public static ViewAction setTime(final int hour, final int minute) {
        return new ViewAction() {
            @Override
            public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) view;
                tp.setCurrentHour(hour);
                tp.setCurrentMinute(minute)
            }
            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Set the passed time into the TimePicker";
            }
            @Override
            public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(TimePicker.class);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: This works well, but for some reason it doesn't invoke the value changed listeners?

Comment: @JoeMaher have you found a workaround about the not triggering change listener?

Comment: @JoeMaher yeah, change listener is not triggering for me as well. Any findings on this?

Answer (score 12):

Match the view and then perform the action:

```
ViewInteraction numPicker = onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(NumberPicker.class.getName())));
numPicker.perform(setNumber(1));
```

Create a ViewAction to set the number:

```
public static ViewAction setNumber(final int num) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) view;
            np.setValue(num);

        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Set the passed number into the NumberPicker";
        }

        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(NumberPicker.class);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with accepted answer : it does not fire on change event. So (if you need it) you can't test if your view react to this on change event.

The following code (kotlin) is not cool anyway but i think it's the only way.

```
fun setValue(value: Int): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {
        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "set the value of a " + NumberPicker::class.java.name
        }

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(NumberPicker::class.java)
        }

        // the only way to fire onChange event is to call this private method
        override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
            val numberPicker = view as NumberPicker

            val setValueMethod = NumberPicker::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
                "setValueInternal",
                Int::class.java,
                Boolean::class.java
            )

            setValueMethod.isAccessible = true

            setValueMethod.invoke(numberPicker, value, true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those looking at this question later (like me) this might be helpful: [DateTimePickerTest](https://github.com/vgrec/EspressoExamples/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/vgrec/espressoexamples/DateTimePickerTest.java) makes use of [PickerActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/PickerActions). PickerActions allows code for date pickers like this (Java):

```
onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(DatePicker.class.getName()))).perform(PickerActions.setDate(year, month + 1, day));
```

Or for time pickers (Kotlin):

```
onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(TimePicker::class.java.name))).perform(PickerActions.setTime(0, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the built-in TimePickerDialog.

[image: ![Looks like this]

(Kotlin)

```
fun setAlarmTime(){

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    onView(isAssignableFrom(TimePicker::class.java)).perform(
        PickerActions.setTime(
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 2
        )
    )
    onView(withText("OK")).perform(click())
}
```

Firstly, you should open the TimePickerDialog, then use this code. The time will be the current time + 2 minute. After the setup, it clicks on the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem, that Luigi Massa Gallerano's solution does not trigger the change listener.

Additionally to his method you need to add a wrapping method, that swipes up and down one time each. This triggers the changeListener, though the former value of course, is lost.

```
fun setNumberPickerValue(viewInteraction: ViewInteraction, value: Int) {
    viewInteraction.perform(setValue(value))

    viewInteraction.perform(GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.SLOW, GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER, GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER, Press.FINGER))
    SystemClock.sleep(50)
    viewInteraction.perform(GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.SLOW, GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER, GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER, Press.FINGER))
    SystemClock.sleep(50)

}
```

The example given is using NumberPicker and Kotlin, but in principle, it's the same.

Comment: unfortunately I could not comment on his solution, because I don't have enough reputation